# upgrade from 15.04 to 15.04?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

I'm running ubuntu 15.04 (German language) and want to upgrade to 15.10. 
If I run the updater as described in the help, click on "update", input my password, I get the screen "Welcome to Ubuntu 15.10 'Wily Werewolf'". After clicking on "update system" it tells me that it's updating to 15.04, which I'm already running.
What's wrong here? Thank You for Your help!